# How can I get Firefox to remember passwords for banking sites?

Tags: firefox, passwords

I wish for Firefox v4 to ask to remember passwords on Windows 7 for many banking sites that somehow cause this feature to be suppressed.  Is there a way in Firefox or a plug-in that will allow these passwords to also be remembered?

Comment: I don't know if this applies in the US, but in the UK, if you had your computer stolen and somebody got into your online banking as a result of this, you could be refused compensation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about web browser functionality rather than using a web application.

Comment: @ale Would it be better served by moving to another StackOverflow site?

Comment: [su] is probably the best bet. However, this is too old to be migrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your Firefox components folder. The default path is

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\components
```

Now open the file `nsLoginManager.js` with a text viewer (Notepad or Notepad++).

Go to the function at around line 804 (varies with version of Firefox), which is:

```
/*
 * _isAutoCompleteDisabled
 *
 * Returns true if the page requests autocomplete be disabled for the
 * specified form input.
 */
_isAutocompleteDisabled :  function (element) {
    if (element && element.hasAttribute("autocomplete") &&
        element.getAttribute("autocomplete").toLowerCase() == "off")
        return true;

    return false;
},
```

Now comment out the first 3 lines, so it becomes:

```
/*
 * _isAutoCompleteDisabled
 *
 * Returns true if the page requests autocomplete be disabled for the
 * specified form input.
 */
_isAutocompleteDisabled :  function (element) {
    /*if (element && element.hasAttribute("autocomplete") &&
        element.getAttribute("autocomplete").toLowerCase() == "off")
        return true;*/

    return false;
},
```

Save it, restart Firefox and you're done.

Comment: Apparently that file is now inside omni.jar which is almost a zip file. I renamed to zip, could view the file and edit, but when I try to put modified file back in the .jar Windows complains about format being corrupt.

Comment: @WilliamKF: I have changed exactly the file `nsLoginManager.js` in the above path; and since then it's been good. I have no idea about omni.jar.

Comment: There is no `nsLoginManager.js` in Firefox 4 on Windows except the one embedded inside `omni.jar`.

Comment: @WilliamKF: The above solution is valid for Firefox 3.x, and at the time you asked your question, you didn't tell that you have Firefox 4. So I answered on April 28th (before your edit) without knowing you have Firefox 4.

Comment: @WilliamKF: The issue of Firefox 4 is discussed under Firefox Support Forums (see [this thread](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/799489)). I also found a solution for `omni.jar` problem as [described here](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2011/04/26/edit-files-inside-firefox-4-omni-jar-to-auto-save-password). Hope that helps.

Comment: I successfully updated _isAutoCompleteDisabled() to always return false with the python script to optimize it as give in above comment, however, passwords are still not being saved for those web sites that request otherwise.

Comment: @WilliamKF: I personally do not like and use Firefox 4 as it brings more problems (see [this](http://superuser.com/q/261319/13567) example). After trying FF4 a few days, I downgraded to FF 3.6.17 and I'm satisfied with it.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say it would be better to use a password manager plug-in like LastPass or 1Password.